# How to concat two getfieldvalue in one in lwc?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, js

```
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

import FIELD1 from '@salesforce/schema/Account.SumOpp__c';
import FIELD2 from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Name';

const fields = [FIELD1, FIELD2];


    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })
    account;

    get field1() {
        return getFieldValue(this.account.data, FIELD1);
    }
 

    get field2() {
        return getFieldValue(this.account.data, FIELD2) + ' ' + this.field1;
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: If this is meant to be a self-answered question, which we certainly encourage, the section *above* this comment should be a self-contained question, and the area *below* should contain the example solution. You can [edit] your question and add your own answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to concatenate two values, your approach looks ok - you could make it a bit clearer by making a third getter to do it though:

```
get field2() {
    return getFieldValue(this.account.data, FIELD2);
}

get concatenatedFields(){
  return `${this.field1} ${this.field2}`;
}
```

Comment: I did in this way and put this variable in label of accordion, but displays Undefined Undefined :                                                           
               <lightning-accordion>
                    <template if:true={data}>
                        <template for:each={data} for:item="acc">
                            <lightning-accordion-section key={acc.Id} name={acc.Name} label={concatenatedFields}>
 Mayby you know how resolve it? Thanks!

Comment: You don't have a `recordId` class attribute defined. `@api recordId;` Also amend the top to: `import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';`